# the same properties for different classes

Tags: actionscript-3

can i give same properties for different classes?

for example two classes that extends Sprite and MovieClip, and both have OasicObj properties.

is this possible somehow?

.

```
public class BasicObj
    {
        public var _id:uint;
        public var _type:String;
        public function SetType(type:String):void {
            _type = type;
        }
    }

public class ObjOne extends Sprite implements BasicObj
    {
        public function ObjOne():void {
            super();
        }
    }

public class ObjTwo extends MovieClip implements BasicObj
    {
        public function ObjTwo():void {
            super();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may implements an interface like this

```
public interface  BasicObj
{

    function set type(value:String):void;
    function get type():String
}

public class ObjOne extends Sprite implements BasicObj
{
    public function ObjOne():void {
        super();
    }

    private var _type:String;

    public function set type(value:String):void {
        this._type = value;
    }


    public function get type():String {
         return this._type;
    }

}

public class ObjTwo extends Sprite implements BasicObj
{
    public function ObjTwo ():void {
        super();
    }

    private var _type:String;

    public function set type(value:String):void {
        this._type = value;
    }


    public function get type():String {
         return this._type;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about an interface. Set up BasicObj as an interface (Put it in its own .as file and replace 'class' with 'interface'). Interfaces contain only the definitions of functions; that is, the function names and their parameter signatures. The functions are implemented in any classes that implement the interface.
Interfaces are AS3's way of implementing multiple inheritance. They also strictly enforce encapsulation.

Comment: Code with interface are just for example. the main question is "two classes that extends Sprite and MovieClip, and both have OasicObj properties"

Comment: You CAN have a class that extends Sprite and a different class that extends MovieClip, and they CAN have similar (or the same) properties, but you might end up having to write some pretty clunky code; If you want to use their properties and methods as if they're interchangeable, you're probably going to have to write a lot of conditionals to check which 'type' they are - Extended Sprite or extended MovieClip. You'd be much better off to implement the BasicObj interface; The objects will then ALSO be of the 'type' BasicObj, so you can instantiate them as such.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from declaring properties of a certain type to subclasses.

```
public class A extends MovieClip {
    public var bo:BasicObj;
    public function A() { 
        super();
    }
}
public class B extends Sprite {
    public var bo:BasicObj;
    public function B() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Then you reference these properties as normal.

```
var a:A=new A();
a.bo=new BasicObj();
a.bo.SetType("A");
```